# Routing After Login zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hi everyone I'm new with Zend Framework 2 , for ruthentification on  my project i used this module (( http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/zend-framework-2-working-with-authenticationservice-and-db-session-save-handler/#comment-5393 )) and i add the field "Role" on data base.

I want to ask how can i make a specific route for any member of user, for example if the user’s Admin when he connect he will be redirected automatically to route “Admin” and if the user’s “visitor” he will be redirected to route “visitor” ???

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/** this function called by indexAction to reduce complexity of function */
protected function authenticate($form, $viewModel)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $dataform = $form->getData();

            $this->authService->getAdapter()
                                   ->setIdentity($dataform['username'])
                                   ->setCredential($dataform['password']);
            $result = $this->authService->authenticate();
            if ($result->isValid()) {
                //authentication success
                $resultRow = $this->authService->getAdapter()->getResultRowObject();

                $this->authService->getStorage()->write(
                     array('id'          => $resultRow->id,
                            'username'   => $dataform['username'],
                            'ip_address' => $this->getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR'),
                            'user_agent'    => $request->getServer('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))
                );

                // your userid -> select the role
                $role = $this->getRoleUser($resultRow->id);
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('success', array('action' => 'index', 'role'=>$role));


            } else {
                $viewModel->setVariable('error', 'Login Error');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then into your success page, just perform some actions using the param **role**

Don't forget to create a function ***$role = $this->getRoleUser($resultRow->id);*** to get the role of the user.

### To implement roles function

check before this documentation to how to configure and create models/database: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

```
protected function getRoleUser($userid){
  $table = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('User\Model\UserTable');
  return $table->find($userid)->current()->role;
}
```

Comment: great thanks for your help , it will be nice if you give me an example of creattion a function " $role = $this->getRoleUser($resultRow->id) "

Comment: It's My first week with ZF2 and it's really hard to start with . thx again

Comment: What is your database schema ? tables ?